# Issue with MS Edge - embedded application on html5 page don't load

Tags: html, web-applications, embed, microsoft-edge

I embed a web-application. It runs on all browser but not on MS Edge. We are forced to work with MS Edge 17.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Meta Tag for edge

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

loading js

```
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall`.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Bannerad_edgePreload.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-160548878 { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->
</head>
```

Stye part

```
<style>
.edgeLoad-EDGE-1689000495 { visibility:hidden; }
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
</style>
```

table where I will ut in my App

```
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong><a class="toggleBut" href="#" data-blend="zeile2">Lernkontrolle durchführen</a></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr id="zeile2" style="display: none;">
<td>
```

embedding the application

```
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-160548878">
    <iframe width="100%" height="680px" src="FILE.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<a class="toggleBut" href="#" data-blend="zeile2"> weniger anzeigen </a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Is there anything I missed about MS Edge? It works now for every second user with the same version of MS Edge. What could I do?

Comment: You did not mentioned, Which issue you are facing when you try to embed your app using Iframe, Object or embed? Are you getting any error or warning message? whats the expected output and what you are getting in MS Edge? also try to inform us, which version of MS Edge and OS build you are using currently? It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi,
i am using MS Edge 17.1734. I wanted to fix the heigth of the application to 720px. It works for all browser but it doens't if I use MS Edge. How could I fix this issue? The javascrit of the application doesn't work neither on MS Edge.

Comment: First I suggest you to update your MS Edge with latest version by updating your Windows OS. If issue persist than try to post your sample code that can produce the issue on our end. you can also post the snapshot of the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: thanks for your answer. I'm not allowed to update it.. I just posted all the code I have. I work with wordpress by the way.

Comment: I try to check your code and find that you had set a inline style to TR tag display: none. https://imgur.com/a/DyEvNEu So because of this reason I was not able to see the embedded app in any browser. I remove that and it started working fine for every browser including MS Edge. You can try to test this on your side and let us know about your testing result. We will try to provide further suggestions if needed.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: i set the display to "none" because i want the user to click on the button for oppening the content.
I just removed the dislay-tag but nothing changed. The application don't load the java scrit on MS Edge and does not adjust the height to 720px.

Comment: I suggest you to make a test on any other machine which have latest MS Edge. Your above code is embedding the web page on my site in MS Edge. Besides that, Did you got any script related errors in your console? Also try to make a test with hosted web page on web server and try to open it using MS Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to face my problem.
I just had to add the following code in the head part:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

I also put the iframe-tag in a "div" container. My application runs now also for MS Edge.